# How to PInvoke scanf instead of Console.ReadLine()?

Tags: c#, c, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

Simple question: i should read some variables from console but i can't use Console class. So i'm writing something like this

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication153
{
    class Program
    {
        static unsafe void Main()
        {
            printf("%s" + Environment.NewLine, "Input a number");
            int* ptr;
            scanf("%i", out ptr);
            printf("%i", (*ptr).ToString());
        }

        [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void printf(string format, string s);

        [DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static unsafe extern void scanf(string format, out int* ptr);
    }
}
```

but it fails with NullReferenceException. Please help, how can i do it? Printf works, but scanf - doesn't. Tnx

Okay. Full task sounds like this: "How to get a variable from user and print it's value in C# withoud using Console class".

Comment: It might be useful to give a bit of background information why you can't use the Console class, because your question currently sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Just don't use this when you don't understand pointers.  Scanf() is fundamentally unsafe and will not take kindly to you passing an uninitialized pointer.  Just write code in C++/CLI if you really want to do this.  In C# you write int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()) for the entirely safe version.

Comment: It's employer's task. Similar to google's questions about "Why hatches are round". It's absolutly nesessary to `use` C# and `do not use` Console class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `%i` you need to pass a pointer to an integer. You are passing a pointer to an uninitialised pointer to integer. Not good.

Declare the function like this:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void scanf(string format, out int value);
```

Passing an int as an `out` parameter is implemented by passing a pointer to an `int`.

Call it like this:

```
scanf("%i", out value);
```

There's no need for unsafe code here.

You'll also want to pass `%s` to `printf` if you are going to pass a string, as you do in your second call to `printf`.

Comment: It doesn't work. Output is: `Input a number
12
4582808Enter any key. . .`

Comment: Fix the printf too. Read my final paragraph.